# 1d Fourier convolution python

Tags: python, fft, convolution

**Problem**

I want to write a very simple 1d convolution using Fourier transforms. My code does not give the expected result.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
def fftconvolve(x, y):
    ''' Perso method to do FFT convolution'''
    fftx = np.fft.fft(x)
    ffty = np.fft.fft(y)
    fftc = fftx * ffty
    c = np.fft.ifft(fftc)
    return c.real

square = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] # Example array

output = fftconvolve(square, square)
output2 = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(square, square, mode='same')
```

**Result**

[image]

Figure presents the convolution using scipy (orange), and my function (blue).

**Question**

Why are the two outputs different?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25950/wrong-amplitude-of-convolution-using-numpy-fft

Answer (score 0):

You get a lot closer if you use 'full' mode instead of 'same'!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
def fftconvolve(x, y):
    ''' Perso method to do FFT convolution'''
    fftx = np.fft.fft(x)
    ffty = np.fft.fft(y)
    fftc = fftx * ffty
    c = np.fft.ifft(fftc)
    return c.real

square = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] # Example array

output = fftconvolve(square, square)
output2 = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(square, square, mode='full')
```

Comment: In fact, I am unsure this is true. If you plot the results: 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(output)
plt.plot(output2, '--')`
You will notice that the outputs  do not have the same length. Moreover the begining (left side of the plot) is very different between the two. Or maybe do I not understand why this is equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
from typing import Literal


def fftconvolve(x, y, mode: Literal['full', 'same', 'valid'] = 'full'):
    _len = {'full': len(x) + len(y) - 1,
            'same': max(len(x), len(y)),
            'valid': max(len(x), len(y)) - min(len(x), len(y)) + 1
            }
    # The full operation is taken first, post operation is taken for 'same' and 'valid' (for the signal boundary)
    length = _len['full']

    def _padding_zeros(arr):
        # padding the signals with 0
        return np.pad(arr, (0, length - len(arr)), 'constant')
    _x_pad = _padding_zeros(x)
    _y_pad = _padding_zeros(y)
    c = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(_x_pad)*np.fft.fft(_y_pad))
    if mode == 'full':
        return c.real
    if mode in ['same', 'valid']:
        start_index = int(np.floor((length-_len[mode])/2))
        return c[start_index: start_index + _len[mode]].real
```

```py
fftconvolve([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], 'same')
# array([ 4.38245931e-17, -1.40238698e-16,  1.00000000e+00,  2.00000000e+00,
#        3.00000000e+00,  2.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.73969861e-16,
#        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00])
# ground truth
# array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

concept: https://alan23273850.gitbook.io/signals-and-systems/di-wu-zhang-li-san-fu-li-ye-zhuan-huan-dft/di-wu-jie-dft-de-ying-yong-er-ji-suan-xiao-gui-mo-shi-yong-de-xian-xing-zhe-ji

ref: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**